# Unable to single-time login with main domain MVC (example.com) and Angular 8 Application (subdomain.example.com)

Tags: cookies, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, local-storage, angular8

I have existing site "example.com" developed in ASP.NET MVC and authenticated via api.example.com(Web API 2) OAuth in "Cookies". Now, adding a sub-domain site (sub.example.com) using Angular 8 and using the authenticated via the API api.example.com(Web API 2) in "local Storage". Both the sites working fine individually. Now, we have a requirement to use single sign on any of the sites should allow to access other sites without asking individual login.

I tried to integrate Angular 8 into existing MVC 5, its caused lots of trouble couldn't proceed on this experiment.

Comment: i too have the same problem. Didn't proceed with the same